# Remaining days taking one date as a reference in Java

Tags: java, date, datetime

I have a variable of type `LocalDateTime` which has a date stored, for example 14/03/2020. I would like to know how I can get the days remaining to be again the 14th day of the month 3; in this case (from August 1, 2022), there are 225 days. I really have no idea how to get that value.

Comment: Sorry, Stack Overflow isn't just *insert requirements, receive solution*. The expectation is that you've made an attempt and can demonstrate that attempt. Start by trying to work out what date you're looking for, then work out how you can calculate the difference between them in days. Take a look at [the API of LocalDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html). Specifically, `plusMonths` and `getDayOfWeek`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Even if you cannot see how to write any code, search and tell us what you think of what you found and what you still see as missing. Showing an effort on your side always provides for a good impression, and it allows us to give much better focused answers.

Comment: Jose, I've made some important improvements to the handling of leap days since you accepted my answer; you may want to review the answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Determine a [year](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html#getYear()) by comparing the [date portion](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/MonthDay.html#from(java.time.temporal.TemporalAccessor)) of the current and reference [dates.](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html) If the date has passed already, use next year; otherwise, use the current year. Then [combine](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/MonthDay.html#atYear(int)) this year with the month and day of month from the reference date to yield the anniversary. Finally, [compute the difference](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html#until(java.time.temporal.Temporal,java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit)) in days between the reference date and the anniversary.

```java
static LocalDate nextAnniversary(LocalDate date, LocalDate today) {
    MonthDay anniversary = MonthDay.from(date);
    int year = today.getYear();
    if (anniversary.isBefore(MonthDay.from(today))) year += 1;
    return anniversary.atYear(year);
}
```

An example of this function in use:

```java
LocalDateTime stored = LocalDateTime.of(LocalDate.of(2020, 3, 14), LocalTime.NOON);
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now(); /* Or, better: LocalDate.now(clock) */
LocalDate anniversary = nextAnniversary(stored, today);
long daysUntil = today.until(stored, ChronoUnit.DAYS);
```

---

Update: This took a few tries to get right. Leap day complicates things; it is best to determine the year first, then to combine it with the original month and day, rather than to increment a past date by one year. (h/t [Basil Bourque](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73199163/3474) and Ole V.V.)

Answer (score 3):

The [Answer by erickson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73198527/642706) is good and proper.  For fun, here are a couple of different solutions. One uses `Period#isNegative` to detect future or past. The other wraps this code as a convenient `TemporalAdjuster`.

## `Period#isNegative`

This code uses [`Period#isNegative`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Period.html#isNegative()) to figure out if the proposed March 14 is past or future.

[`MonthDay`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/MonthDay.html) is a way to represent, well, a month and a day-of-month, without any particular year.

Be aware that determining today’s date requires a time zone. Each day starts earlier in the east than in the west. So while it may be “tomorrow” in Tokyo Japan, it can simultaneously be “yesterday” in Edmonton Canada. If you omit an explicit time zone, the [JVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine)’s current default time zone is applied implicitly.

```java
public static long daysUntilMarch14 ( ZoneId zoneId )
{
    LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( zoneId );

    MonthDay march14 = MonthDay.of( 3 , 14 );
    LocalDate then = today.with( march14 );

    if ( Period.between( today , then ).isNegative() ) { then = then.plusYears( 1 ); }
    return ChronoUnit.DAYS.between( today , then );
}
```

Example usage.

```
long days = daysUntilMarch14( ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) );
```

See this [code run live at Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/GTUb5d).

> 225

You could also write a test for past or future as:

```
if( today.with( MonthDay.of( 3 , 14 ) ).isBefore( today ) ) { … add one year … }
```

## `TemporalAdjuster`

If you want to get fancy, you could implement this code as a [`TemporalAdjuster`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjuster.html). For similarity, see [`TemporalAdjusters.next(DayOfWeek dayOfWeek)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html#next(java.time.DayOfWeek)) API, and [its source code](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.java).

```java
public static TemporalAdjuster nextMarch14 ( )
{
    return ( Temporal temporal ) -> {
        MonthDay march14 = MonthDay.of( 3 , 14 );
        Temporal then = temporal.with( march14 );
        if ( ChronoUnit.DAYS.between( temporal , then ) < 0 )
        {
            then = then.plus( Period.ofYears( 1 ) );
        }
        return then;
    };
}
```

Usage:

```
LocalDate
.now( ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) )
.with( UntilMarch14.nextMarch14() )
```

See this [code run live at Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/HyJa7H).

> 2023-03-14

Be aware that in *java.time*, in day-to-day work we do *not* make use of the more general interfaces, abstract classes, and superclasses. Those are intended for internal use only, generally. The Javadoc advises the use of the more concrete classes for regular work. But here, in creating a `TemporalAdjuster`, we are acting as if doing internal *java.time* work, so we make use of [`Temporal`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/temporal/Temporal.html).

Comment: I think this answer handles leap days better than mine for most use cases. That is, a date of March 14 in a leap year is treated as March 14, not as the 74th day of the year (in most years, the 74th day is March 15).

Answer (score 0):

```
    LocalDateTime localDatetime = LocalDateTime.of(2020, 03, 14, 0, 0);
    LocalDate date1 = localDatetime.toLocalDate(); //convert localDateTime to localDate 
    LocalDate date2 = date1.plusMonths(3); //add n months
    long days = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(date1, date2); //get days in between
```

You can use ChronoUnit (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html) to get the number of days in between.

Comment: That should help the OP on the right way. The way I read the question they wanted to count from today’s date (1 August 2022) to next 14 March (in this case 14 March 2023).